# Is there a way to use the Javascript SpeechRecognition API with an audio file?

Tags: javascript, html, speech-recognition

I want to use the [SpeechRecognition api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition)  with an audio file (mp3, wave, etc.)
Is that possible?

Comment: Have you seen https://ctrlq.org/code/20280-google-cloud-speech-api

Comment: @Stuart yes, but I don't want to use an external service, thanks tho.

Comment: @TheSurrican - how I wonder, is that so very different to the one already employed? I mean, text-recognition doesn't work when you're offline - it requires access to an external service also - admittedly, one doesn't need to explicitly connect to some url, but just like droid and fruit phones, no external data - no speech.

Comment: text-recognition --> speech-recognition

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The short answer is **No**.

The [Web Speech Api Specification](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/webspeechapi.html#speechreco-section) does not prohibit this (the browser could allow the end-user to choose a file to use as input), but the audio input stream is never provided to the calling javascript code (in the current draft version), so you don't have any way to read or change the audio that is input to the speech recognition service.

This specification was designed so that the javascript code will only have access to the result text coming from the speech recognition service.

Comment: _"The short answer is No."_ , _"you don't have any way to read or change the audio that is input to the speech recognition service"_ That is not accurate.

Comment: @guest271314 The Web Speech API specification does not specify any way for you to read or change the audio input. Do you have any example from that spec that suggests otherwise?

Comment: _"The Web Speech API specification does not specify any way for you to read or change the audio input."_ What do you mean by "read or change the audio input"? You can render any audio that you decide to.

Comment: _"Do you have any example from that spec that suggests otherwise?"_ See _"[5.1.2 SpeechRecognition Methods](https://w3c.github.io/speech-api/speechapi.html#speechreco-section)
start method
When the start method is called it represents the moment in time the web application wishes to begin recognition. When the speech input is streaming live through the input media stream, then this start call represents the moment in time that the service must begin to listen and try to match the grammars associated with this request."_ The audio output of an `<audio>` element is streaming live

Comment: @guest271314 yes, all of that is correct, but you as user of the API are not able to specify an audio file as an argument to the `start()` method, or any other member of the SpeechRecognition API.
The audio input is decided by the user-agent (browser), and the current implementations only use the microphone as an audio input.
But, as I saied, the spec doesn't prohibit the browser from allowing the end-user (human) to specify an audio file as input, instead of the microphone, but this still is not a choice that is given to the programmer, and is not specified in the spec.

Comment: The choice is provided to the programmer. The user 1) decides to allow the browser to access the microphone; 2) decides which audio will be available to be input to the microphone when `.start()` is called; 3) decides when `.stop()` is called. If an individual presumes that the specification mandates that the input be a live human voice then that presumption would be incorrect. The choice is left to the user as to the above three facts. _"The short answer is No."_ is not supported by facts.

Comment: @guest271314 I'm not sure what your argument is, but the spec doesn't specify a way for the **programmer** to supply a audio file directly to the Speech Recognition API. *That is a fact*.
Of course the user could connect their audio output to their microphone input and play an MP3 file and it would work. But the Speech Recognition API doesn't specify a way for the programmer to supply it's own audio input (like a file), which was what the OP was looking for.

Answer (score 9):

Basicly you may use it only with `default` audioinput device which is choosen on OS level...

Therefore you just need to play you file into your `default` audioinput

2 options possible:

## 1

- Install https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/
- Update system settings to use VCable device as `default` audiooutput and audioinput
- Play your file with any audio player you have
- Recognize it... e.g. using even standard demo UI https://www.google.com/intl/fr/chrome/demos/speech.html

Tested this today, and it works perfectly :-)

## 2

THIS IS NOT TESTED BY ME, so I cannot confirm that this is working, but you may feed audio file into chrome using Selenium... just like

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome(); 
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--allow-file-access-from-files",
                     "--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream",
                     "--allow-file-access",
                     "--use-file-for-fake-audio-capture=D:\\PATH\\TO\\WAV\\xxx.wav",
                     "--use-fake-device-for-media-stream");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

But I'm not sure if this stream will replace `default` audioinput

Answer (score 1):

Andri deleted this post but I will repost it as I believe it to be the most accurate answer, besides the hackish answers above:

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) you CAN'T do that. You can't feed any stream into recognition service

That's a big problem... You even cannot select microphone used by SpeechRecognition

That is done by purpose, Google want's to sell their CLOUD SPEECH API

You need to use services like [CLOUD SPEECH API](https://cloud.google.com/speech/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=emea-ua-all-ru-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-b-gcp-1002258&utm_content=text-ad-none-any-DEV_c-CRE_187895214676-ADGP_BKWS+%7C+BMM+%7E+1%3A1_UA_RU_ML_Speech+API_google+speech-KWID_43700017149188146-kwd-31931985581-userloc_1012866&utm_term=KW_%2Bgoogle%20%2Bspeech-ST_%2Bgoogle+%2Bspeech&ds_rl=1245734&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIsLehpLnF1gIVB4uyCh0ZtQ0bEAAYASAAEgI9rfD_BwE&dclid=CPTivae5xdYCFQjJsgodtbMP7A)

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just start the SpeechRecognition engine using the mic and playback the audio file via speakers to have feed back into the mic. It worked for me when I tested it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible to get the text transcript of the playback of an audio file using `webkitSpeechRecognition`. The quality of the transcript depends upon the quality of the audio playback.

```
const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();

const audio = new Audio();

recognition.continuous = true;
recognition.interimResults = true;
recognition.onresult = function(event) {
  if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
    // do stuff with `event.results[0][0].transcript`
    console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript);
    recognition.stop();
  }
}

recognition.onaudiostart = e => {
  console.log("audio capture started");
}

recognition.onaudioend = e => {
  console.log("audio capture ended");
}

audio.oncanplay = () => {
  recognition.start();
  audio.play();
}

audio.src = "/path/to/audio";
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/guvn1yq6/

Comment: interesting, thanks. but it needs to play the whole thing? there is no way to do it quickly, without the user needing to listen to it and/or wait for the duration of the audio file?

Comment: Wrong, it may work in your local computer just because sound from your speakers come to your microphone :-)

Comment: @TheSurrican No. The user needs to grant permission to capture the media device.

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky What do you mean by "Wrong"? The code returns expected result when permission is granted to use microphone and headphones are not plugged in which would prevent microphone from capturing audio output to speakers..

Comment: @guest271314 Just imagine an automated software for Speech Recognition which processes files one by one by playing it to Speakers and then Microphone captures it and then... That doesn't seems like real "use case" :-) What do you think about building speech recognition farm based on this approach, the only question to resolve is SOUNDPROOFING of several computers!

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky User action is required to grant permission to capture sound from the microphone.

Comment: @AndreyMuzalevsky Are you referencing https://arstechnica.com/security/2015/06/not-ok-google-chromium-voice-extension-pulled-after-spying-concerns/?

Comment: @guest271314 I can't get your solution working just because I have no speakers, only headset :-) Is it hardware problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155435/discussion-between-andrey-muzalevsky-and-guest271314).

Comment: @TheSurrican fwiw, see also https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2013Mar/0000.html, https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-speech-api/2017Jul/0004.html

Comment: I would like to add my input that I tested this solution and it does not work.