# Web Speech API filter audio input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, audio, google-chrome-extension, webspeech-api

I am using Web Speech API for a chrome extension. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Speech_API)

What I want to do is filter the audio being sent to the recognition instance. Does anyone know of a way to do this? The API really only gives you controls to the output of the recognition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use the Javascript SpeechRecognition API with an audio file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46267816/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-javascript-speechrecognition-api-with-an-audio-file) _"the audio input stream is never provided to the calling javascript code [...], so you don't have any way to read or change the audio that is input to the speech recognition service."_

Comment: Ah yes. Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible. Thanks for saving me from jumping down an endless rabbit hole though haha.