# How can we use an stream with Web Speech API in 2020?

Tags: javascript, webspeech-api

I want to feed a recorded mp3 audio to Web Speech API (feed any stream to the SpeechRecognition).

I come up with some answers on web that tell us this is impossible but I found a comment on Stack overflow who says this is possible and provide a code to prove his claim.

The first comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448941/13849624

He said:

> You can feed any stream to the SpeechRecognition, as the audio is
> captured to the microphone of the computer.

But the fiddle he provided is not working...

Here is the code:

```js
    const recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
    
    const src = "https://audio00.forvo.com/phrases/mp3/c/8/c81c2618ae7246e5148df5892df485a2_9261923_39.mp3";
    
    const transcript = document.getElementById("transcript");
    
    const audio = new Audio();
    
    recognition.continuous = true;
    recognition.interimResults = true;
    recognition.onresult = function(event) {
      if (event.results[0].isFinal) {
        console.log(event.results[0][0].transcript);
        transcript.textContent = event.results[0][0].transcript;
        recognition.stop();
      }
    }
    
    recognition.onaudiostart = e => {
      console.log("audio capture started");
    }
    
    recognition.onaudioend = e => {
      console.log("audio capture ended");
    }
    
    audio.oncanplay = () => {
      recognition.start();
      audio.play();
    }
    
    fetch(`https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from data.uri where url="${src}"&format=json&callback=`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(({
          query: {
            results: {
              url
            }
          }
        }) =>
        audio.src = url
      )
      .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<div id="transcript"></div>
```

I can't understand what he did...

How can we use an stream with Web Speech API?

Answer (score 1):

as you can also see in the comments from your link to https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383699/4278324:
this does not actually stream audio to the Web Speech API implementation

it loads the audio and then plays the audio (through speakers) - so the recognition will only work in real time AND if there is a physical speaker AND if the microphone is able to record the speakers sound